# Kivy Spinner: is any event triggered when a value is selected from the Spinner

Tags: events, spinner, kivy

I introduce a `Spinner` in my widget, and I want to perform some action every time I chose a different value from it.

Is it possible?

I only seem to get events `on_press` and `on_release`, but they are not triggered when a choice for a different value is made :-(

Best regards,

Bojan

Comment: I guess I have found it ... `on_text`

Comment: on_text is the right way to do it if you just want to be notified when the selected value changes. We should probably add an event that fires whenever the user makes a selection, but it's currently inconvenient to detect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - `on_text` is actually pretty good, but for some reason it took me several hours to figure it out.  If only it was mentioned in here: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html

Comment: on_text no longer seems to work; have you found any alternatives?

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean on_text no longer seems to work?  It works fine for me (in Kivy 1.9.1)

Answer (score 9):

Beacuse the spinner updates its text property every time attr:values are changes,
I would do someting like this:

```
    Spinner:        
      text: '<select>'
      values: ['White', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green']
      on_text: root.on_spinner_select(self.text)
```

In python code:

```
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
  def on_spinner_select(self, text):
    print (text)
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to use on_text:

```
spinner:
       id: my_spinner
       values: ("Home", "bureau", "kitchen")
       on_text: if my_spinner.text == "Home": root.Home()
                elif my_spinner.text == "bureau": root.bureau()
                else: root.kitchen()
```

now in python:

```
def Home():
   "do your things"
def bureau():
   "do your things"
def kitchen():
   "do your things"
```

Answer (score 0):

For future people finding this thread:
Another option that worked for me (but is pretty ugly) is to override the `_on_dropdown_select` of `Spinner`, eg:

```
class MySpinner(Spinner):
    def _on_dropdown_select(self, instance, data, *largs):
        super()._on_dropdown_select(instance, data, *largs)
        # put your code here
```

The advantage over on_text is this doesn't get called when text is changed in another way, eg in a RecycleView