# Kivy Spinner on_text action when widget made on python-side

Tags: python, kivy

I am interested in a solution that is similar to this question:
[Kivy Spinner: is any event triggered when a value is selected from the Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31721385/4816207)

In that, I need a spinner to trigger a function when it's text value changes, but I need this to happen when the widget is made purely from the python side.

For example:

```
mySpinner = Spinner(text='Choose something', values=['1','2'], on_text=myFunction)
```

Does not trigger myFunction when `1` or `2` are selected. However, using `on_release` will trigger, but BEFORE a value is selected. How can I pull this off from purely the python side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below illustrates a Spinner widget made purely from the python side.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

spinner = Spinner(
    # default value shown
    text='Choose something',
    # available values
    values=('1', '2'),
    # just for positioning in our example
    size_hint=(None, None),
    size=(150, 44),
    pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})


def myFunction(spinner, text):
    print('The spinner', spinner, 'have text', text)


spinner.bind(text=myFunction)

runTouchApp(spinner)
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: Thanks! As a side note to future coders looking at this MWE, be sure to test the arguments passed to myFunction. For example, my spinner is embedded with a screen, so the code should be modified to `def myFunction(screen,spinner,text):`